# how to slow down the modal dialog and submit an email form

Tags: jquery, dialog, modal-dialog

when I click the submit button, the dialog box flashes on the screen instead of taking 3 seconds to fade out.  i am new js and jquery, so please dumb your answer down for me so that I can understand. :)  Here is my **(EDITTED 9/1**) code:

```
<html>
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title></title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js">
</script>
<script src="http://recp.rm04.net//ui/library/formValidate.js" language="javascript">
</script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/ui-
lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<STYLE TYPE="text/css">
     BODY, .BODY, TD
     {  color: ;
        font-size: ;
        font-family: ;
        font-weight: ;
        text-decoration: ;
        font-style: ;
     }
     </STYLE>
</head>
<body vlink="" alink="" link="" bgcolor="">
<!--  demo -->
<div class="demo">
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
<p>Email submitted successfully.  Thank you for signing up!</p>
</div>
</div>

<!-- End demo -->
<br>
<br>
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
<form name="form" method="post" action="http://links.mkt41.net/servlet/UserSignUp?
f=755449&postMethod=HTML&m=0&j=MAS2">
<tr>
<td valign="top"><span style="color:#CC0000">*</span></td><td valign="top"
align="left">Email:</td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="EMAIL_REQUIRED" value="T"><input type="hidden"
name="EMAIL_DATATYPE" value="email"><input type="text" name="EMAIL" value=""
maxlength="4000"></td>
</tr>
</form>


<form> 
<tr>
<td align="center" colspan="3">
<!--<div id="opener"> -->
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" onClick="f_validateForm()">
<!--</div> -->
<script language="javascript">

$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
autoOpen: false,
show: "fade",
hide: "fade",
open: function() {
    var dlg = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
        dlg.dialog("close");
    },
    3000); 
},

modal: true,
opacity: 1
});

$('form').submit(function() {
e.preventDefault();
$.post('http://links.mkt41.net/servlet/UserSignUp?
f=755449&postMethod=HTML&m=0&j=MAS2&EMAIL_REQUIRED=T&EMAIL_DATATYPE=email', {

        EMAIL: $('input[name=EMAIL]').val()
    },
    function (data) {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
});
</script>
</td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
<p>
</p>
<script>f_initializeForm();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there actually a line break after `UserSignUp?` ? They whole string needs to be on one line. I'm also not seeing the removed `</form><form>` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the dialog on a form submit button, which means you're leaving the page when the form is submitted. You're seeing the dialog for a brief moment before you leave the page. You'll need to use Ajax to submit your form data without leaving the page.

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('http://links.net/servlet/UserSignUp?f=755449&postMethod=HTML&m=0&j=MAS2&EMAIL_REQUIRED=T&EMAIL_DATATYPE=email', {
            EMAIL: $('input[name=EMAIL]').val()
        },
        function (data) {
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
        });
});
```

Also want to note that you can not have two elements on the same page with the same id, currently you have a div and a input that both have the id of "opener".

To send the user to another page after the dialog closes you'll have to add a close callback to your dialog. See the example below:

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: "fade",
    hide: "fade",
    open: function(event, ui) {
        var dlg = $(this);
        setTimeout(function(){
            dlg.dialog("close");
        },
        3000); // wait 3 seconds before closing
        // Change the above number to the amount of time
        // (in milliseconds) that you want to wait before
        // closing the dialog.
    },
    close: function(event, ui) {
        window.location.replace("welcome_page.html");
    },
    modal: true,
    opacity: 1
});
```

Replace `"welcome_page.html"` with the url that you want the user to be directed to.

Comment: hey thanks man!  Yes, I see the two IDs.  I meant to delete the one in the button. I'll try out your suggestion and let you know!

Comment: Make sure you remove the `$( "#opener" )` click function that's opening the dialog from your code. I'm opening the dialog as a callback from the Ajax. Ideally you be checking in the callback  to see if the request was successful before displaying the dialog that says it was successful.

Comment: I tried your solution, Rusty, but I can not get it to work.  The dialog box does not open in Chrome, IE8 or FF.  In IE8, I'm getting the following js error:

Object doesn't support this property or method
formValidate.js
Code: 0
URI: http://recp.rm04.net/ui/library/formValidate.js

Comment: I've editted/updated the code above to include the AJAX code.  What am I doing wrong here?  I'm sure it worked for you to post it.  THANKS!

Comment: There are two form tags.  Should they have IDs to differentiate?

Comment: There should not be two form tags, try removing the `</form> <form>`.

Comment: I'll have to start a new post I guess since I thought this was answered.  @Rusty, I removed the <form></form> tags as you said. I get the dialog box to show and slowing fade out, but now I don't get the confirmation welcome page returned after successful submission.  When I put the <form></form> tags back, I get the "welcome" page.  Why is this happening and how do I fix?

Comment: I added info on redirecting the user to the welcome page after submission.

Comment: Thank YOU! I will add your solution right away.  I really appreciate your help!

Comment: i have pasted the entire revised code at the top.  The modal no longer works at all.  I don't know where the page is redirecting to.  Is it possible just to have the modal appear after the email form is submitted and the page just refresh itself so that the input box is empty?

Comment: Rusty, I found there is server code that is consuming the form & storing in a remote DB then sending a redirect with a confirm msg.  I would need to be able to access the web form setup in that database/s.  This must what is hindering the code you wrote for me from working. I'm a student trying to do freelance to build my skills (pro bono at the moment!) so I'm unable to do this for that community service project.  Many thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Well sounds like you might not need the dialog if it's redirecting to a confirm message. What was the reason for using the dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$( "#opener" ).click(function() {
   $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" ).delay(3000).fadeOut();
   return false; 
});
```

Comment: thanks!  I'll try that.  I don't know how to order the syntax and adding the functions/methods(?) (delay, fadeOut) all on one line like that.  If you don't mind my asking, how does one know to write it like that?

Comment: That's called 'chaining', and it's how jQuery was designed to work. Each method returns the same object, and passes it to the next method.

Comment: No change.   < BEGIN CODE:><div id="opener"><input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" onClick="f_validateForm()" /></div>
<!-- js/jq here -->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  show: "fade",
  hide: "fade",
  open: function(event, ui) {
  var dlg = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
  dlg.dialog("close");
  },
  10000); 
 },
  modal: true,
  opacity: 1
});


$( "#opener" ).click(function() {
   $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" ).delay(10000).fadeOut();
   return false; 
}); </ END CODE >

Answer (score 0):

To your last question, I've noticed that Internet Explorer does not like `<form>` tags in between elements in tables.

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
<form action="#">
<tr>
...
</tr>
</form>
</table>
```

Your form may not behave as expected in IE8 like this. You need to move your `<form>` tags outside of the table such as:

```
<form action="#">
<table>
<tr>
...
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks!  I got the code from a developer.  I was surprised to see the table layout, but everybody has their way of coding, right?  I will try your solution!

Comment: there are two form tags in the code within the table.  Moving them one outside while the other one remains within?  I'm going to redo this in CSS once I get the modal dialog box to perform correctly.

Comment: Has this post has lost interest? None of the above solutions work.  I included the Entire HTML/css/jquery code so that the correct code could be inserted where ever it needs to be to work.  Anybody else?